# Comments for Custom Post Types with the Genesis Framework

Tags: wordpress, comments, genesis

I have a plugin that creates a custom post type and has a custom template file for loading these post types. The site is using a Genesis child theme as well. The comments load fine on posts and I have them disabled on pages. I'd like for them to load on the custom post types as well.

Comments are supported by the custom post type. I've tried calling `comments_template()` as well as some of the Genesis functions directly from the `comments.php` file and the framework's functions. None of them have worked to this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in functions.php where portfolio is the name of your CPT

```
add_post_type_support( 'portfolio', 'comments' );
```